# Python Seaborn heatmap with custom order on both axes and values from a frequency table (data included)

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have this data in a frequency table. I just want to be able to create a heatmap with Fac1 on Y axis, Fac2 on X axis and the frequency values as heatmap. The order of the Factors in Fac1 and Fac2 must be maintained in the same sequence (after removing duplicates from both Fac1 and Fac2 columns). I haven't been able to get this working after so many tries but I've managed to get the data in order and the simplest representation. I'd greatly appreciate any help in this.

```py
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
    import seaborn as sns
    
    url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rroyss/stack/main/dfso.csv"
    df = pd.read_csv(url)

    plt.subplots(figsize=(15,30))
    plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=10, labelbottom = False, bottom=False, top = True, labeltop=True)

    sns.heatmap(df, cmap="Blues", linewidth=1, xticklabels=True, yticklabels=True)
```

Comment: @JohanC will this fix the order in which the factors are displayed on the Y and X axes? That's been the main problem.

Comment: Thanks @JohanC From what I've experimented, and after quite a bit of sorting data into this order so that higher frequency pairs appear on top, the resulting heatmap doesn't follow this order. The heatmap should reflect higher frequencies in the top left of the plot. But sns.heatmap makes the axes in alphabetical order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert your dataframe if you want to sue `heatmap`:

```py
df2 = df.drop_duplicates().pivot_table(index='Fac1', columns='Fac2', values='Frequency Fac1-Fac2 pair', sort=False)

plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 30))
plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=10, labelbottom=False, bottom=False, top=True, labeltop=True)

sns.heatmap(df2, cmap="Blues", linewidth=1, xticklabels=True, yticklabels=True)
```

This is the result (zoomed on the first rows and columns):

[image]

Comment: this I was able to get as well or similar using crosstab but this still doesn't solve the the order problem on X and Y axis. Do you know if that can be fixed as requested in the question. Thank you for taking the time.

Comment: Updated, you have to use `sort=False` in the pivoting function

Comment: a small follow up question, do you know how to move the 'Fac2' axis label to appear on the top of the figure, like above the xticklabels? Thanks

Comment: I got it done using `ax.xaxis.set_label_position('top')`

Answer (score 1):

You first need to reorganize the dataframe such that Fac1 becomes the index, Fac2 the columns, and the values are aggregated from the third column. E.g. df_pivoted = df.pivot_table(index='Fac1', columns='Fac2', values='Frequency Fac1-Fac2 pair').

The heatmap will use the order provided by the columns and index as created by `pivot_table`. Keeping the original order is a bit tricky, but can be achieved by `pd.Categorical` (which forces an order) combined by `pd.unique()` (which keeps the original order, unlike `np.unique`).

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rroyss/stack/main/dfso.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(url)
df['Fac1'] = pd.Categorical(df['Fac1'], categories=pd.unique(df['Fac1']))
df['Fac2'] = pd.Categorical(df['Fac2'], categories=pd.unique(df['Fac2']))
df_pivoted = df.pivot_table(index='Fac1', columns='Fac2', values='Frequency Fac1-Fac2 pair')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 30))
sns.heatmap(data=df_pivoted, cmap='Blues', xticklabels=True, yticklabels=True, ax=ax)

ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=10, labeltop=True, top=True, labelbottom=False, bottom=False)
ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelrotation=90)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.heatmap keeping original order]

If you are aiming for a 2d histogram or kde plot where the last column is intended as weights:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rroyss/stack/main/dfso.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(url)

df['Fac1'] = [int(f[5:]) for f in df['Fac1']]
df['Fac2'] = [int(f[6:]) for f in df['Fac2']]

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(20, 10))

sns.histplot(data=df, x='Fac1', y='Fac2', weights='Frequency Fac1-Fac2 pair', bins=20, color='blue', ax=ax1)
sns.kdeplot(data=df, x='Fac1', y='Fac2', weights='Frequency Fac1-Fac2 pair', color='blue', ax=ax2)

for ax in (ax1, ax2):
    ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=10)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: seaborn 2d histplot and kdeplot]

Comment: The data is qualitative, and only frequencies are available for how often the two factor pairs are mentioned. So heatmap seems to be appropriate to select the pairs with higher frequencies or above a threshold. Will give a good visual and identifiable way to illustrate my point.

Comment: Many thanks @JohanC for the detailed answers and a new way to present the data while answering the original question as well.